# Invertible Matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if A is a square invertible matrix and $A^3=A$ then $A$ is its own inverse.

$A^3=A$

$A^3A^{-1}=AA^{-1}$

$A^3A^{-1}=I$
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: write $A^3$ as $A^2*A$ in your last line

Comment: Alternatively, remember that the usual rule $A^nA^m=A^{n+m}$ holds for the matrices in question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
A^3&=A\\
A(A^2-I)&=0\\
A^2&=I\\
A&=A^{-1}
\end{align}